# Improve multiple fitting Lorenztian on python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, data-fitting

I'm currently trying to fit 10 lorentzian on a spectrum with curve_fit from scipy. I just define a function which is the sum of 10 lorenztian + a background offset. My code is working but I think this is not the best way to do it because it doesn't seem pretty and it takes about 4 min to compute.

I'm asking for new way to do multiple fitting because I want to improve this type of work.

```
def lorentzian(x, amp1, cen1, wid1, amp2, cen2, wid2, amp3, cen3, wid3,\
                 amp4, cen4, wid4, amp5, cen5, wid5, amp6, cen6, wid6,\
                amp7, cen7, wid7, amp8, cen8, wid8, amp9, cen9, wid9,\
               amp10, cen10, wid10, a):
    return (amp1*wid1**2/((x-cen1)**2+wid1**2)) +\
            (amp2*wid2**2/((x-cen2)**2+wid2**2)) +\
             (amp3*wid3**2/((x-cen3)**2+wid3**2)) +\
              (amp4*wid4**2/((x-cen4)**2+wid4**2)) +\
               (amp5*wid5**2/((x-cen5)**2+wid5**2)) +\
                (amp6*wid6**2/((x-cen6)**2+wid6**2)) +\
                 (amp7*wid7**2/((x-cen7)**2+wid7**2)) +\
                  (amp8*wid8**2/((x-cen8)**2+wid8**2)) +\
                   (amp9*wid9**2/((x-cen9)**2+wid9**2)) +\
                    (amp10*wid10**2/((x-cen10)**2+wid10**2)) + a   

p0 = np.concatenate((_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, [a]))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lorentzian, freq, filtre, p0=p0)
fit = lorentzian(freq, *popt)
```

Here is my main function. I define by and the p0 values to help curve_fit and then I plot it.

I think there are better way to define my function and I really want to here some new ideas !

[image: This is the plot after running the code]

**EDIT** Here is a link to my data and my entire .py file.
https://github.com/MaloBriend/ucl/tree/1039abe797e0031a876093c20513c02c841a4fae

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What information are you trying to learn from your curve fit?

Comment: @jared How to optimise my code in term of speed and accuracy

Comment: Is there a reason to not user an interpolator?

Comment: I don't know what it is.

Comment: Interpolation is a method of connecting points with a function (often polynomials). The scipy methods are available in [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html). For this problem, you can use [`scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline) to smooth out the data a bit. The application of interpolation depends on what your goal is. I asked this already, but you didn't answer: what are you trying to learn from a curve fit?

Comment: Ok I see, my data are already filtered btw. I want to learn how to make an accurate fit as I said.

Comment: can you add a link to the data to your question?

Comment: @jared I added a link to my data in the edit of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Do not copy-and-paste an expression ten times; use vectorization.

This should not take four minutes! It should (and does) take less than a second when properly implemented.

You need to be plotting semilog and not linear scale.

The following is a semi-realistic demonstration of fitting where we do a first-pass peak finding with knowledge of the noise floor.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

F_RESOLUTION = 1e6


def synthesize() -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)
    f = np.arange(start=-1.7e9, stop=1.8e9, step=F_RESOLUTION)
    width = 5e6 + rand.uniform(low=-1e6, high=1e6)
    amp =    np.array(( 0.005,  0.005, 0.26,   0.02,   0.02, 0.001,  0.02,  0.14,  0.02,  0.04))
    centre = np.array((-1.6e9, -1.3e9, -1e9, -0.5e9, -0.2e9, 0.3e9, 0.6e9, 0.9e9, 1.4e9, 1.7e9))
    pure = (
        amp*width**2 / ((f[:, np.newaxis] - centre)**2 + width**2)
    ).sum(axis=1)
    noisy = np.clip(
        pure + rand.uniform(low=-2e-4, high=2e-4, size=f.size),
        a_min=0, a_max=None,
    )
    return f, noisy


def get_peaks(f: np.ndarray, spectrum: np.ndarray) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    peak_idx, _ = scipy.signal.find_peaks(
        x=spectrum,
        height=5e-4,
        distance=100e6/F_RESOLUTION,
    )
    peak_order = np.argsort(spectrum[peak_idx])
    peak_idx = peak_idx[peak_order][-10:]
    peak_freq = peak_idx*F_RESOLUTION + f.min()
    peak_amp = spectrum[peak_idx]
    return peak_freq, peak_amp


def lorentz(f: np.ndarray, *args: float) -> np.ndarray:
    amp, centre, width = np.array(args).reshape((3, -1))
    spectrum = (
        amp*width**2 / ((f[:, np.newaxis] - centre)**2 + width**2)
    )
    return spectrum.sum(axis=1)


def make_guess(amp0: np.ndarray, centre0: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    width0 = np.full_like(centre0, 4e6)
    return np.concatenate((amp0, centre0, width0))


def fit(f: np.ndarray, spectrum: np.ndarray, guess: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n = guess.size//3

    params, _ = curve_fit(
        f=lorentz,
        xdata=f,
        ydata=spectrum,
        p0=guess,
        bounds=(
            ((0,)*n + (f.min(),)*n + (1e3,)*n),
            ((1,)*n + (f.max(),)*n + (1e8,)*n),
        ),
    )

    return params.reshape((3, -1))


def plot(f: np.ndarray, spectrum: np.ndarray, guess: np.ndarray, params: np.ndarray) -> plt.Figure:
    ax: plt.Axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.scatter(f, spectrum, c='blue', s=1, label='Experiment')
    ax.semilogy(f, lorentz(f, guess), c='green', label='Guess')
    ax.semilogy(f, lorentz(f, params), c='orange', label='Fit')

    ax.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    ax.set_ylabel('Cavity transmission (V)')
    ax.set_ybound(lower=1e-5)
    ax.legend()
    return fig


def main() -> None:
    f, spectrum = synthesize()
    peak_freq, peak_amp = get_peaks(f, spectrum)
    guess = make_guess(peak_amp, peak_freq)
    params = fit(f, spectrum, guess)

    print('Parameter table (amplitude, centre, width):')
    print(params.T)

    plot(f, spectrum, guess, params)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Parameter table (amplitude, centre, width):
[[ 9.91063242e-04  2.99997567e+08  5.11840090e+06]
 [ 5.02728448e-03 -1.60009375e+09  5.38846566e+06]
 [ 4.88591262e-03 -1.29998945e+09  5.52068207e+06]
 [ 1.99150343e-02  1.40001165e+09  5.29239119e+06]
 [ 1.99581243e-02 -4.99993715e+08  5.27934769e+06]
 [ 1.98832569e-02 -2.00027858e+08  5.31880182e+06]
 [ 1.99795151e-02  5.99996444e+08  5.28726278e+06]
 [ 4.00437270e-02  1.70000304e+09  5.26566084e+06]
 [ 1.40041881e-01  9.00000992e+08  5.27369662e+06]
 [ 2.59989040e-01 -1.00000048e+09  5.27544352e+06]]
```

[image: fit]

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is getting a "good" fit, then you can use an interpolator to fit the data. I used [`scipy.interpolate.splrep`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep) with [`scipy.interpolate.splev`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html#scipy.interpolate.splev) since it allows for some smoothing (using the `s` keyword argument). I included a small amount of smoothing since the data still has lots of little bumps.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

plt.close("all")

file = "CSV1605FSR.csv"

def readcsv(file,header=11):
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header=header)
    time = np.array(data["Second"])
    ramp = np.array(data["Volt"])
    mode = np.array(data["Volt.1"])
    filtre = savgol_filter(mode, 301, 2)
    return time, ramp, mode, filtre
time, ramp, mode, filtre = readcsv(file)

tck = splrep(time, filtre, s=0.01)
interpolated = splev(time, tck)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,8))
ax.plot(time, filtre)
ax.plot(time, interpolated)
```

[image]

If you just want the locations of the peaks, then you can use [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html). You need to include some parameters so it doesn't pick up every little bump. Using `height=0.001` says that the peaks should be at least 0.001 in height (from 0), `width=300` says the base of the peak should be 300 points wide, and `distance=5000` says that the peaks should be at least 5000 points apart. (I believe using just `width` or `distance` is sufficient for this problem.)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter, find_peaks

plt.close("all")

file = "CSV1605FSR.csv"

def readcsv(file,header=11):
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header=header)
    time = np.array(data["Second"])
    ramp = np.array(data["Volt"])
    mode = np.array(data["Volt.1"])
    filtre = savgol_filter(mode, 301, 2)
    return time, ramp, mode, filtre
time, ramp, mode, filtre = readcsv(file)

peaks = find_peaks(filtre, height=0.001, width=300, distance=5000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,8))
ax.plot(time, filtre)
ax.plot(time[peaks[0]], filtre[peaks[0]], "x")
```

[image]